# MOngoDB Repair Exception

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongorestore, mongorepository

I am trying to repair command from the code below...

```
 mongod --dbpath /someser/arbiterDB/project/data  --config  /mongoDB/config/pro/mongo.conf --repair
```

I am getting a below exception

```
2019-08-08T15:19:27.045+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in 
initAndListen: NotMaster: Not primary while creating collection 
admin.system.version, terminating
2019-08-08T15:19:27.045+0800 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutting down 
replication subsystems
2019-08-08T15:19:27.045+0800 W REPL     [initandlisten] 
ReplicationCoordinatorImpl::shutdown() called before startup() finished.  
Shutting down without cleaning up the replication system
2019-08-08T15:19:27.045+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine 
shutting down
```

What could be the error? In the config file i have set the `BindIp` and `Replication`.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to repair a replica set member while replication is active. In general, you should [resync a replica set member](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) rather than attempting to repair. A repair operation will salvage data but may result in an inconsistent state for a data-bearing secondary. However, based on your path of `arbiterDB`  it seems like this member may actually be an arbiter. In that case, you should be able to stop the `mongod`, move (or remove) the current contents  of the `dbpath`, and then restart the service.

Comment: Can you describe the error message or issue you are trying to fix by running repair? Also, what is the exact  version of the MongoDB server (x.y.z)?